# Is there a PHP solution for copying a text from Word doc and paste in a text-area and still get URLs

Tags: php, forms, textbox

I want to create a some kind of a `<textarea>`/textbox on my page, that when you copy from a word document a paragraph with links, and when I submit a form (PHP) - it gets the text as an  exactly how the doc looks like.

The only solution I have found for this is using something like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Is there a better PHPish solution for this? Or other HTML text-area tag I don't know of in HTML that does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,you can do it easily using TinyMCE